# Debugging NewExecutable binaries

Tags: tools, debuggers, ne

I'm trying to debug a 16-bit Windows executable (format: New Executable). The problem is that all the standard tools (W32DASM, IDA, Olly) don't seem to support 16-bit debugging.

Can you suggest any win16-debuggers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Turbo Debugger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borland_Turbo_Debugger) has a Windows 3.x version (`tdw.exe`) that supports NewExecutable files, and works out of the box under Windows XP.

Answer (score 6):

[OpenWatcom](http://www.openwatcom.org/) has full support for Win16 including debugging, though I personally haven't tried it. It even has remote debugging support over TCP/IP, serial and a couple other protocols.

Older SoftICE versions also supported Win16, you may try your luck with that.

Comment: You're absolutely right (how could I forget, as a big Watcom fan?!).
The windows (non-NT, `C:\WATCOM\binw\wdw.exe`) debugger handles NE without any problem, and runs under XP without any problem.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a [list and links](http://www.exetools.com/debuggers.htm) to old debuggers, that had **16-bit Windows** executables in list of supported binaries once. Most of them require older system installed, but You may install them in VM env, for example - [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/).

In case there is a requirement for **16bit DOS debugger** as well - have a look on [Insight debugger for DOS](http://www.bttr-software.de/products/insight/)

Comment: To avoid confusion: HACK, TR,... only supports COM/EXE, OllyDbg only PE...